# PHP : How to make color image by color code

Tags: php, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Colorize a PNG image using PHP GD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279255/colorize-a-png-image-using-php-gd)

hi

i saw that

it's link: `http://themecraft.net/wwwdata/colorimg.php?c=CCCC33`

it's link: `http://themecraft.net/wwwdata/colorimg.php?c=669933`

it's link:`http://themecraft.net/wwwdata/colorimg.php?c=99CC99`

and i liked that and wanna do that .. i tried but i failed

how can i do that

Comment: You tried but failed? How about showing us what you tried so we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should hopefully get you going:

```
// Try by going to file.php?c=FF0000

$color = isset($_GET['c']) ? hexdec($_GET['c']) : 0;

$blue = $color & 0xFF;
$green = ($color >>= 8) & 0xFF;
$red = ($color >>= 8) & 0xFF;

header('Content-type: image/png');
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 90);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($image, $red, $green, $blue));
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```